# Why CocoapPods don't accept comments on classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm trying to submit my first CocoaPod spec, and for validation I'm still missing removing all comments from my code. This is what I get from the terminal:

```
- WARN  | Comments must be deleted.
- WARN  | Comments placed at the top of the specification must be deleted.
```

I'm wondering, how should I do it? Since the headers and implementations are fully documented, and I don't want to sacrifice all that job. Plus, the repo it self will also be available on Github for people without Pods installations.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### the warning relates to your pod spec file,

not to the header/implementation of the classes

Comment: :) hehe. happened to me too when I wrote my first pod spec :D

Comment: I guess it should be clarified somewhere on the comments at the top of the specification. It wasn't that user-friendly IMHO. Thanks again!!